# How to prevent Windows from activating keytips when alt-key is held down?

Tags: windows, autohotkey

Try it yourself:

In file explorer when you keep the alt-key held down then keytips appear on the ribbon.

I want to prevent this behavior. In short, I want to disable alt-key held-down behavior but keep alt+anyOtherKey shortcuts enabled.

In AutoHotkey I tried the code:

```
Alt::return
```

It disables alt-key single-press but does not disable alt-key held-down behavior. Any ideas?

Comment: I have no solution for you. BUT, `Alt Up::Return` does prevent the keytips... (it also prevents all normal alt-combinations from working.) If you have an `Alt & [letter]::` hotkey, this negates the `Alt Up::Return` hotkey. I also looked to see if there was some registry setting that controls keytips or keytip delays, but found nothing.

Comment: @EvanElrod thanks for the comment

Comment: Can u replicate this behaviour with a different application than file explorer?

Comment: @John yes, this same behaviour is with ms-word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
~LAlt::vk07
```

or

```
~LAlt::
~RAlt::
    Send {Blind}{vk07}
return
```

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_MenuMaskKey.htm#Remarks

Comment: Awesome find! Any reason for specifying L and RAlt instead of just `~Alt::vk07`?